# Use OSRM and OVERPASS as extern memory o postprocess tracks?

Tags: gps, maps, overpass-api, osrm

I have to obtain the streets and the max speed of each street from a tracks that are a set of gps positions (lat, lon).

I have got two strategies, which is better:

- While i generating the track I obtain the streets and the max speed using OSRM API and OVERPASS API (local installation in my servers), and save the info to my mongo DATABASE where are the tracks (assigning and ID to the street and the maxspeed.

For example in each track I could have, an array of streets with the maxpspeed with a index, and each coordinate in the track will have that index to map the street. Like this;

```
[date, 36.434123, -7.33821321, ..., [street_index]],
[date, 36.433123, -7.33822321, ..., [street_index]],
[date, 36.432123, -7.33823321, ..., [street_index]],
```

- Using OSRM API and OVERPASS API like extern memory and query to those on the fly when the user ask for a track and so on.

What are you opinions?